# How to disable Blogger Default Js on post pages only

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

I don't use blogger default templates , i have a custom built one.
and I have read that we can disable blogger default js with 1 of 2 options :
option 1 : adding a `b:js='false'` within html tag

option 2 : replace `</body>` with `&lt;!--</body>--&gt; &lt;/body&gt;`

but whenever i do any of these options, my JQuery (which is loaded from an external file) stops working, the thing is: JQuery is essential to home page, label pages and search pages ... but it's not needed much on post pages , so my question is: is there some way to disable blogger default js on post pages only ?

Comment: You will have to share the relevant parts of your template, so that we can help.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is CSP (Content Security Policy) `<meta>` tag. You can totally prevent the default blog script by inserting a `<meta>` tag that allow only your preferred JS source to be loaded. Combined with blog widget tags it will be something like :

(I'm using the latest version data tags for this example. For the best result, place this before the **include all-head-content** data tag)

```
<b:if cond='data:view.isSingleItem'>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src https://cdn.example.net; 'unsafe-inline' 'none'">
</b:if>
```

Note that by not loading the default script provided by Blogger, you comment system won't work at all (also all widget related buttons will be gone from the blog view)

Do not rely on example. YMMV. Here's a reference :
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/